# How do I create or update a model based on one of its attributes? (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, updates, ruby-on-rails-5, seed

I’m using Rails 5 and PostGres 9.5 . I have a model with the following field …

```
 title             | character varying           |
```

I would like to either create or update a model in my db/seeds file based on its title, which is a unique constraint.  So I tried

```
scenario = Scenario.find_or_initialize_by_title(s.title)
scenario.update_attributes(Hash[*@record.attributes.except('created_at','updated_at','id').map { |a| [a.first, nil] }.flatten])
```

but I got the below error.  What’s the correct way to create or update my model and also exclude the listed attributes?

```
localhost:sims nataliab$ rake db:seed
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_or_initialize_by_title' for #<Class:0x007fb22d28f820>
Did you mean?  find_or_initialize_by
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:21:in `method_missing'
/Users/nataliab/Documents/workspace/sims/db/seed/scenarios.rb:165:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/nataliab/Documents/workspace/sims/db/seed/scenarios.rb:164:in `each'
/Users/nataliab/Documents/workspace/sims/db/seed/scenarios.rb:164:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/Users/nataliab/Documents/workspace/sims/db/seeds.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:549:in `load_seed'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:268:in `load_seed'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:196:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Try: `Scenario.find_or_initialize_by(title: s.title)`

Answer (score 1):

The error message gives you the clue:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_or_initialize_by_title' for #<Class:0x007fb22d28f820>
Did you mean?  find_or_initialize_by
```

The dynamic method names are now not really "Rails-approved"  you should instead use `find_or_initialize_by`. In this case you'd use:

```
Scenario.find_or_initialize_by(title: s.title)
```

Here's a link to the api doc on this method: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_initialize_by

Comment: Thanks, but if there is no title, and using your code, the following line gives a "NoMethodError: undefined method `attributes' for nil:NilClass" error.  My goal is to create the object if the title doesn't exist, or update attributes of an existing model if it does exist.

Comment: That goal is exactly what this code would do. What do you mean that there is no title? why is it saying that Scenario is nil? do you have a model called `Scenario` ? does it have a column in the db called `title` ? if not then yes this code will fail.

Comment: Have a look at the api doc for `find_or_initialize_by` - it also covers things like how to pass in a block that gives all the other field-values. Also consider `find_or_create_by(title: s.title)`

Comment: Excuse me, I don't know what I was writing -- there is a title, but if there is no model matching the title, the following line is throwing the error I mentioned -- "NoMethodError: undefined method `attributes' for nil:NilClass".  I tired your suggestion about replacing "find_or_initialize_by" with "finid_or_create_by" but I still get the above error on the line where I attempt to update attributes.

Comment: weird... find-or-intiialize by should not return a nil - it should return a newly instantiated object with the given title.

Comment: It is indeed returning a non nil object but there's something about the next line that is throwing the error -- not because the "scenario" object is nil but something else

Comment: right... so there's a bug in that line. So how about instead of trying to do it all in one line, you split it into smaller chunks first (eg mapping the data to actual attributes, then passing in the attributes) and see which line is the one that breaks. Then once you figure out the bug, you can choose whether to mangle it all into a one-liner again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `Scenario.find_or_initialize_by(title: s.title)`

Comment: This actually should have provided the answer to the question - it directly addresses the problem as stated. Unfortunately under this bug seems to be another, separate bug.